# If And - and Statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have the below formula which works absolutely fine but I would like this formula to also check if column "Q2" contains the word "LOCKWOODS" how would I add this into my pre existing formula please?

If Q2 does not contain the word Lockwoods along with the criteria of the formula below the formula needs to return the word "OK"

**=IF(A2=0,"",IF(AND(A2="Released",N2="No"),"ERROR","OK"))**

Any help is very much appreciated!

Many Thanks,

Kind Regards,

Comment: Add `,Q2="LOCKWOODS"` after `N2="No"`?

Comment: Thank you, sorry if this was a stupid question, I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to this :P